# Creating a Custom UserControl TestContainer for Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms

I like to use the "UserControl TestContainer" that works great for testing a controls properties during design time. Yet it has limitations. Usually, I just create a Windows Form Application to test the control's run-time interface. It would be nice to combine the two phases. Today, I discovered that the test-container is defined in the project file as show below.

*What I like to do is create my own test-container and use it for my Windows Forms Control Library projects in Visual Studio 2008.* I cannot find any specific documentation, and the documentation I found was related to MSTest and not helpful. Any help, suggestions, or research directions for implementing my own test-container?

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Service Include="{94E38DFF-614B-4cbd-B67C-F211BB35CE8B}" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The "Service element above just runs the UserControlTestContainer.exe executable, passing the assembly name as a parameter.

Comment: Give us at least a rough idea how many months you want to work on this.

Comment: One day. It is just a form with an area for an instance of the user-control and a property-grid set to the control instance. The "UserControl TestContainer". In my case, I would add a list-box and use "event-spy" to display the control events as they happen, and allow the user to set the control's Anchor, Dock, and other "layout" properties.

Comment: It would be just like runnning Visual Studio to debug design-time, so I do not see the difficulty. Don't tell me "Hans Passant" that you become a nay-sayer. :O)

Comment: @Hans Passant: Four hours. Now I can fix some of the limitations.

Comment: It still works after 13 years for classic .NET.  Add <Service Include="{94E38DFF-614B-4cbd-B67C-F211BB35CE8B}" /> as the last line in ITEMGROUP that contains references to your usercontrol in your .csproj file. It took some time to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Service` element above runs the *C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\UserControlTestContainer.exe* executable, passing the assembly path as a parameter.

Using .NET Reflector, I modified my existing testing application to behave like UserControlTestContainer, then copied into the IDE folder, and everything works well.

Lastly, I modified my new "user-control test-container" application to accept forms and controls, in addition to user-controls.